# Is there a way to bundle the client socket.io.js with phonegap?

Tags: cordova, socket.io

I have converted a website into a phonegap app. it basically all works, except that socket.io doesn't work anymore on the client (Android in my case). 
i'm using **socket.io v.1.0** and a **nodejs server**.

the normal website version runs fine, the phonegap app runs only fine when i source the socket.io.js from the server, in my case i've used this in the index.html:

```
<!-- this seems to be the only working way for phonegap...-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://192.168.0.11:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

but i wanted to package all js files into the phoegap app so they can be sourced from file://.

i've tried to wget that file into a directory under phonegap's www directory and then use that like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/socket.io.js"></script>
```

i've even tried the official client js source from https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.6.js, i.e. downloaded it and tried to package it into the phonegap app.

simply no luck to package the socket.io client js into the phoegap app.
the error is always that socket doesn't work, when i debug using the chrome dev tools it errors with this:

```
$(function(){
  socket = io('http://192.168.0.11:3000');
  ....
```

**ReferenceError: io is not defined**

does anyone have a way to package socket.io client js into phonegap? or at least an explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: Let me guess. Where is the first HTML file (index.html) file located? If the file is on the webserver then all subsequent request will be prepended with the webserver address i.e `http://yourWebServer/sourcfile`. can you try using the file protocol i.e `file://assets/www/js/libs/socket.io.js`. You will need enable CORS. I hope it works.

Comment: the files are all in phonegap's www folder **using phonegap 3.4**. and when i start the phonegap app the nodejs server doesn't log any file fetches. i.e. i am pretty sure it sources index.html from the file in phonegap. or must i specify file:// for phonegap?

Comment: if the index.html file is in the phone than `src="js/libs/socket.io.js"` should work. Can you put the code fragment where you are getting the error?. I do not have much experience with socket.io. I hope you have downloaded all the library files in the libs directory pertaining to the socket.io library.

Comment: hi Frank, i've edited the question for this. the 'io' object should be provided by socket.io.js.

Comment: hi Frei, You have mentioned in your post that you have done a `wget` for `socket.io.js`. Does this meant that there is a **single/only** `socket.io.js` file copied to the js/lib directory. If yes, than it will not work. You need to copy the **entire** (including subdirectories) `socket.io` library from [here](https://github.com/automattic/socket.io-client).

Comment: When debugging with the chrome tools, you should be able to see if the socket.io.js script was loaded or not -- check the Sources tab of the console. If it is loaded, double check to make sure it looks (roughly) like the same one you downloaded.